# The uploaded files are not converted to Google Documents

Tags: google-drive-api

I use Google Drive API to upload new files (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert), and I use the 'convert' parameter to convert the file in Google Document.

It worked well but today, the uploaded files are not converted.
I tried with a .doc, .docx and .ppt, and I have the same problem.

Does anyone has an idea? Is the API has been changed?

Comment: For information, the format of the uploaded file doesn't seem to be detected.

When I go to drive.google.com, we see the unknown file icon  (https://ssl.gstatic.com/.../icon_10_generic_list.png).

When I open the file and I look at the details, the mime type is 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=ISO-8859-1', which is well corresponds to a docx file.

When I upload the file directly to drive.google.com, the file is recognized as a Word file with the same mime type, 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.word...'.

Comment: Can you post the specific request you are making?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct mime type. See code below.

```
Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(...).setApplicationName(...).build();
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("file1.doc");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.document");
AbstractInputStreamContent inputStream = new InputStreamContent(null,
                new FileInputStream(new java.io.File("/file1.doc")));
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, in).setFields("id").execute();
```